# C trying to cast a void pointer to another type

Tags: c, pointers, void, void-pointers

Alright here's the code:

```
//in another file

void **ptr; ptr = kmalloc(sizeof(void *) * 2);

  *(ptr+0) = tf; //type trapframe *
  *(ptr+1) = as; //type addrspace *

func(*ptr);
```

And here is that function:

```
void func(void *ptr) {

struct trapframe *parentTF = ptr[0];
struct addrspace *newAS = ptr[1]; 
//now I wanna do stuff with parentTF and newAS

}
```

And the error I get is:

```
warning: dereferencing `void *' pointer
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to do, it seems like you need to change this:

```
void func(void *ptr) {
```

to this:

```
void func(void **ptr) {
```

and this:

```
func(*ptr);
```

to this:

```
func(ptr);
```

Note that `*(ptr+0)` and `ptr[0]` are synonymous, as are `*(ptr+1)` and `ptr[1]`.

Comment: yeah I'm trying to convince myself of the similarities of pointers and arrays. Thank you very much, I think these changes worked. I honestly have a hard time with pointers even though I've supposedly known C for 3 years. It's sorta sad.

Comment: @YoungMoney: You're welcome. I think the general consensus is that pointers are hard. And C, with its tendency to lapse into "undefined behavior" instead of "printing a stacktrace and exiting" when you get it wrong, seems designed to make it harder. :-P

Comment: It depends on where you're coming from. Since I programmed in assembly language for years, the idea of a pointer, which is simply a machine address, and a pointer variable, which is simply a register or location that holds an address, seems intuitive. Add to that the notion of typed pointers, addresses of a specific type of object, and you're done, except for groking the syntax, which should be read right to left (e.g., pointer to pointer to void).

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `ptr` as a `void **` but using it as a `void *`.  They're different.

Answer (score 1):

First cast the void pointer array to an array of the pointer type you want. i.e, you need to do such changes:

`((trapframe **)ptr)[0] = tf; //type trapframe *`

and another cast like this:

`struct trapframe *parentTF = ((trapfname**)ptr)[0];`

Comment: Since this is C, the struct keyword is necessary. And since ptr points to an array containing both a `struct trapframe *` and a `struct addrspace *`, those casts aren't accurate. Correct is `ptr[0] = (void *)tf;` or `ptr[0] = tf; /* cast to void* isn't needed in C */` and `struct trapframe *parentTF = (struct trapframe *)ptr[0];` (Of course, even more correct would be to declare ptr to point to a struct containing a `struct trapframe *` and a `struct addrspace *`.)

Answer (score 0):

In `func`, where `ptr` is declared as a `void*`, `ptr[0]` is the same as `*ptr` and `ptr[1]` is the same as `*(ptr + 1)`. You're attempting to dereference a `void` pointer, as your compiler's telling you.

If you want to pass an array of `void` pointers to `func`, then you would make the following changes:

- Change the signature of `func` to:

  `void func(void **ptr)`
- Change `func(*ptr);` to simply `func(ptr);` to pass the dynamically allocated array `ptr` to the function.

I also don't understand why you'd split the declaration and initialisation of `ptr` in the top snippet into two statements. Just have:

```
void **ptr = kmalloc(sizeof(void *) * 2);
```

or even:

```
void **ptr = kmalloc(sizeof(*ptr) * 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

And what did you expect? The function's parameter `ptr` is a pointer to "something" (i.e. `void`). You dereference that pointer with `ptr[0]` and `ptr[1]`, trying to extract "somethings". But the compiler doesn't know the type or size of "something".

What you probably want is this:

```
func(ptr);
```

and this:

```
void func(void** ptr)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code screams wrongness because of the inconsistencies between the two files. In one, you access ptr[0] and ptr[1], while in the other you access *(ptr + 0) and *(ptr + 1) ... that happens not to be a source of error here because the two syntaxes mean the same thing, but using two different forms is bad style, reads badly, and is error prone. But then, in one file you declare `void **ptr` but in the other file you declare `void *ptr` -- that can't possibly be be right, since the two ptrs have the same semantics (they each point to an array of two elements, a tf and an as). In one file you have a function that takes a parameter called ptr, but in the other file you pass the *contents* of a variable named ptr ... again, since the two ptrs have the same semantics, this inconsistency must be wrong, and clearly it's the dereference that is wrong. Remove that and you're passing a `void**`, so that's what the parameter of func should be.

Code consistently and a whole class of errors will disappear from your code. You can code for 3 years or for 30 years, but it doesn't matter if you don't learn such fundamentals.